# Module '"node:process"' has no exported member 'dlopen'

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc

I have the following code in my Typescript project (`node@18.14.0, typescript@5.2.2, @types/node@20.6.5`) in the `index.ts`:

```
import { dlopen } from "node:process";
```

`nodemon index.ts` run successfully (my local addon is loaded and executed)

`tsc` however failed with `error TS2339: Property 'dlopen' does not exist on type 'Process'`

I had a look and found out `dlopen` actually does NOT exist in `node_modules/@types/node/process.d.ts` (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/v18/process.d.ts) and even does NOT appear in the whole local and global `node_modules` (text search was done).

I guess `dlopen` must somehow exist in nodejs run-time that's why `nodemon index.ts` worked but type definition for it just doesn't exist.

How can I fix / workaround the issue?

Comment: Sounds like something to [report](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues) and perhaps offer a PR for.

Comment: _"I guess `dlopen` must somehow exist in nodejs run-time that"_ -- software is not about guessing. Of course `dlopen()` exists, it is [described in the Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/process.html#processdlopenmodule-filename-flags). The package `@types/node` (and the `@types/*` packages, in general) is not an authoritative source of information; it provides only hints to the TypeScript compiler that does not have any other source of information about what types or functions Node.js exports. Most probably `@types/node` needs to be updated.

Comment: Thanks @T.J. Crowde and axiac After I fixed it with AKX's suggestion below https://stackoverflow.com/a/77501405/3168315, your comments become make sense to me and I think you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding a new local `types.d.ts` declaration file in your project for the `dlopen` function:

```
declare module 'process' {
  export function dlopen<T = any>(module: any, filename: string, flags?: any): T;
}
```